# What is this plant with white flowers found in the German Alps?

Tags: identification

The picture was taken in the German Alps in about 1500m. What is it?

[image]
*Click for full-size*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with European plants, and I can't find a checklist of the flora of Germany, but this looks very much like a cinquefoil (*Potentilla*). *P. caulescens* looks to be a common species of rocky alpine areas in western Europe ( "[In the Alps](http://www.biome-explorer.net/Mountains/Alpine%20Mountain%20Vegetation.html) *Potentilla caulescens* is often the main character species of carbonate rock in the true alpine zone").

[image]

source: [Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Potentilla_caulescens_(Kalkfelsen-Fingerkraut)_IMG_28242.JPG)